# Newrelic response time less than total time

Tags: .net, .net-core, newrelic

Looking at the following image :

[image]

How come the response time (blue line) is below the yellow part (mongo)?
Response time should be the sum of all operations time.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Response time can be less if requests are [non-blocking/asynchronous](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apm-ui-pages/monitoring/response-time-chart-types-apm-browser/)

> The relationship between response time and total amount of time reflects how much concurrency is taking place within the instrumented code in your application.

> If response time is less than the total time spent, you are taking advantage of concurrency with a non-blocking or asynchronous computing model.

**EDIT**

Created a topic in [newrelic discuss](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/newrelic-response-time-less-than-total-time-mongodb/141809) and found [similar issue](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/mongo-processing-time-is-very-wrong-on-newest-agent-5-2-0/77694/13)

> I’ve updated to the latest NewRelic Agent 5.2.0 recently, which seems to have increased support for the regular MongoClient (non-async).

> Seems like something is very bad in the timing calculations.

Comment: Hi. I have an API which is the Mongo Layer. All async methods there are being AWAITED. so baically it runs async but it's being awaited. so I dont understand why  do I see mongo on top of  the response time : https://i.imgur.com/HimXzT9.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir request isn't waiting for db operation to finish and return response before db operation finished

Comment: I know perfectly well what is async/prallel operations are. but my API doesn't have non awaited operation. client must wait for db in order to continue. so I still dont understand why do i see reponse time bellow .....

Comment: @RoyiNamir do you have db operations that been executed without calling the API?

Comment: no. the API is the only/single  path to mongo

Comment: @RoyiNamir Opened new topic https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/newrelic-response-time-less-than-total-time-mongodb/141809

Comment: We're using .net / .net core

Answer (score -1):

Response time is the duration of a transaction from the perspective of the requester, and not necessarily the total sum of all time spent within a transaction.

It is expected that response time is less than the total time when Async is used in the transaction.